# angularJS - recompile code

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using a search engine on my webapp with angular JS. To highlight the search results it encapsulate the matching keywords in  tags.
However when I print the results with angular like this:

```
<p> {{ myresults.value }} </p>
```

I printed the  rather than compiling them so I get:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit <em>amet</em>, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna <em>aliqua</em>.
```

How can I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: You'll have to share more context and code for us to help.  What search engine are you using?  What is the full code?  Are your results in an Angular view w/ its own controller?  IS the myresults variable stored in the scope?  In your code are their really spaces after the '{{' and before the '}}'?  Can a valid variable name start or end with a space?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have JSfiddle for this? Make use of `ng-bind-html-unsafe`

Something like

```
<p ng-bind-html-unsafe="myresults.value"></p>
```

[Read more on AngularJs Doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml) or checkout [Example Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/ngdoc%3aexample-example16@snapshot?p=preview) from doc